# What is the US English for "soppy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, transatlantic-differences

According to [the online Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/soppy), in British English the word *soppy* means:

> showing or feeling too much of emotions such as love or sympathy,
>   rather than being reasonable or practical: a film with a soppy ending
>
> That's one of the soppiest stories I've ever heard! Some people are
>   really soppy about their pets.

Or as an alternative definition, the OED offers:

> Full of mawkish sentiment; foolishly affectionate; inane, indulgent;
>   occas. used affectionately.

Is there an equivalent US English word?

---

The story so far...

It seems that the usage of soppy to describe a person is that one that is hardest to translate to US English. Would a US English person understand "She is very soppy when it comes to her children." and if not, is there a US English equivalent?  It seems so far that you can't say "She is very sappy/saccharine when it comes to her children." and have a similar meaning.

Comment: Please supply source attributions for those citations.  Why would *soppy* be restricted to Britain?  Also, do you consider *soppy* and *sappy* as meaning two different things?

Comment: So, what's wrong with "soppy", or one of the synonyms listed above???

Comment: chocolate-box, cloying, drippy, fruity, gooey, lovey-dovey, maudlin, corny, mushy, novelettish, saccharine, sappy, schmaltzy, sentimental, sloppy, slushy, soppy, soupy, spoony (or spooney), sticky, sugarcoated, sugary, wet (http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mawkish)

Comment: @tchrist My American friends don't recognise the use of soppy in, for example, "She is much soppier than her friends when it comes to children.".  And, I do regard sappy and soppy as words with quite different meaning/usage. It is worth adding that sappy doesn't exist in British English except maybe in the context of trees :)

Comment: I think most Americans are familiar with the term *soppy stories*. But to describe someone as soppy might be lost on them.

Comment: I hadn’t realized that *sappy* was unknown in Britain. I’m a tad surprised your American friends wouldn’t get a film with a soppy ending though.

Comment: @Mazura Oh, I see what you mean. Curious.

Comment: "A slushy film/movie" appears to work on both sides of the Atlantic, although neither is very common.

Comment: +1 for @HotLicks's suggestions. But I challenge the premise - the US term for *soppy* is *soppy*. It happens that [*soppy* is used less in the US than in the UK](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=soppy%3Aeng_us_2012%2Csoppy%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csoppy%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoppy%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0), but *soppy* is still a term, even if not the only term, for *soppy*.

Answer (score 5):

Initially, I assumed that the AmE **sappy** was merely a varied spelling of the BrE **soppy**. However, tchrist alerted me to some difficulties with that assumption and, in fact, according to etymonline, *soppy* (originally) was in reference to the quality of *excessive wetness* (and in AmE: sopping or soaking wet), while *sappy* appears to be a reference to *tree sap*. **Despite their disparate origins, it seems the two words have evolved to share the sense of excessive sentimentality**.

> [**sappy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sappy) *adjective*
>
> 3a: **overly sweet or sentimental**
>
> 3b: lacking in good sense: silly

(Merriam-Webster *online*)

> [**soppy**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=soppy+&searchmode=nl) (*adj*.) "**very wet**," 1823, from *sop* + -*y* (2). Meaning "**sentimental**" first recorded 1918. Related: *Soppiness*.
>
> [**sappy**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sappy&allowed_in_frame=0) (*adj*.) "full of sap," Late Old English *sæpig*, from *sæp* (see sap (n.1)). Figurative sense of "**foolishly sentimental**" (1660s) **may have developed from an intermediate sense of "wet, sodden"** (late 15c.). Earlier, now obsolete, figurative senses were "full of vitality" (1550s) and "immature" (1620s). (etymonline)
>
> [**sap**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sap&allowed_in_frame=0) (n.2) "simpleton," 1815, originally especially in Scottish and English schoolboy slang, probably from earlier *sapskull* (1735), *saphead* (1798), from *sap* as a shortened form of *sapwood* "soft wood between the inner bark and the heartwood" (late 14c.), from sap (n.1) + wood (n.); so called because it conducts the sap; **compare sappy**. (etymonline)

Comment: Isn't sappy somewhat pejorative?

Comment: @LittleEva I don’t think they’re two different spellings for the same word, but rather two different but closely allied words. The OED says they come from different starting points: *sop* versus *sap*.  But those aren’t all that far apart.

Comment: @Juniper Yes, *sappy* isn’t usually used with affection.

Comment: None of these terms tend to be used without some note of derision.

Comment: @HotLicks That's universally not true with respect to soppy in my experience.

Comment: @tchrist, thanks for the 'heads up* on that, I was jumping to an assumption. According to etymonline, soppy alludes to the quality of wetness, while sappy appears to be related to tree sap, though it seems the two words have evolved to mean essentially the same things.

Comment: @juniper Can you think of a non-negative use of _soppy_? I can’t. I wouldn’t say _sappy_ is downright pejorative, nor _soppy_; but they both contain the same element of undesirability to me. (And did you mean as you wrote that the derisive aspect to _soppy_ is universally untrue, i.e., that _soppy_ is **never** negative? Or merely that it’s not universally true, though sometimes it is?)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Yes. "She is much soppier than her friends when it comes to children."  Or "A film with a soppy ending".  Neither is pejorative. It is sometimes used pejoratively, that much is true.

Comment: See, I would consider both of those to describe qualities that the speaker doesn’t find desirable. Not necessarily derisive or pejorative as such, that’s too strong a word—but definitely not neutral, either. _Sappy ending_ is the standard American English term for the movie ending, and the connotation is precisely the same to me: it’s sentimental to a point where it’s too much of a good thing.

Comment: juniper, doesn't "*She is much soppier than her friends when it comes to children*" always carry the connotation of *excessively emotional or  sentimental*?

Comment: Excess can be desired: [Need really soppy romcoms to watch!!](http://www.thestudentroom.co.uk/showthread.php?t=2289459)

Comment: @Carsten Schultz - sure, we all have our moments of weakness, then again, we don't call them virtues.

Comment: @LittleEva I think it carries the connotation of "emotional and sentimental" not always with the "excessively" part.  But in any case, the question is do US English speakers understand this use of soppy when it relates to people?  If not, can you call a person "sappy" and have a similar meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the word **saccharine** which is defined below:

> excessively sweet or sentimental.

Comment: Thank you but I am not sure you can describe a person as saccharine can you?

Comment: Yes, you most certainly can :]

Comment: OK. How would you compare the meaning of "She is very soppy when it comes to her children." and "She is very saccharine when it comes to her children." ?

Answer (score -4):

I hesitated to post but decided to.  If this is an honest forum to consider even constructions which are not PC, then here you go.

This is used ALL the time in speech.  It’s too “gay”.  It’s never written but is the common man’s tongue for sappy.

Please direct all hate mail to op.

Update.

I just know I'm in trouble, but here it goes again.  Sappy definitely doesn't mean gay, but gay can mean sappy.  Doesn't make sense does it.  While “gay”, generally, is used to indicate effeminate behavior, it’s not always so.

With Yankee “recreational” colloquial speech an analogy/term/phrase (the excessive use of which a British speaker would describe as “you know, the way Americans speak”) can mean a 100 things.  It is SO contextual.  If you were in a conversation with a Yankee, and he said, “Oh that’s just too gay”, it could mean:  it’s outrageously colorful, the wrist is too limp, the product is flimsy, the hair style is over-the-top, excessive whimpering … and on forever.  It'not generally a plus.

For example; I’m in bar and a friend orders a drink with a parasol stuck in the ice cubes.  I guarantee you someone would say, “Man, that’s just too gay!” (in this case he’s saying it’s effeminate).   And it’s just as likely, if we are with the girls, a female would say it.  Many times when the phrase is used “man up” is sure to follow.   And if a woman orders that same drink, she too might be subject to the same quip.

Or let’s say we’re discussing a friend that is too emotional or “sappy”.  I might reply that, “Yah, he’s just too gay.”

The use of the word gay in the contexts described has nothing directly to do with homosexuality, even thou it is commonly used to describe a male homosexual. (If you do want to be insulting years ago you would have used gay, but now one would use the word “fag” or “faggot” (which, when I was in England, meant cigarette).

Is the word pejorative?  I find it’s usually used in teasing one’s friends.  But like all this kind of nonsense it can mean anything.  You really have to be THERE; in other words you can't really use it in prose... unless you are a really good writer.

The Flintstones used to own this word, then the homosexuals did, but now the common man does again, albeit with a different meaning.  (It doesn't mean happy anymore - and is never used that old way.)

Again, all hate mail to the OP.

Comment: I'm quite familiar with *sappy* meaning 'overly emotional or sentimental,' but I've never heard *sappy* used to mean *gay*? Can you find some examples and post them in your answer?

Comment: I just know I'm in trouble.

Comment: No, you're not in trouble here. EL&U does ask users to be respectful when expressing themselves, and in discussing topics that are (or should be) academic subjects. Here we're focused on **English language usage and etymology**, not politics or religion (and definitely not cultural alienation). Can you abide by these slight limitations? If so, post.

Comment: Slang use of "gay" seems a lot more generic to me. I'd say "gay"usually just means "lame" or "stupid" rather than "soppy" in particular. Looking at Urban Dictionary, I find "gay" defined as something **bad**, that someone doesn't like, or something **stupid** or **boring**, but not "sentimental" (i.e. "soppy").

Comment: @sumelic And there are many other common usages of terms to mean *bad, dumb, inferior, weak, disdained* that use race, ethnicity, gender,  orientation* as a stand-in. Because we have a history of using these put-downs doesn't mean we should continue to do so.

Comment: @bib: I'm not making any judgement here; I'm just saying that even from a semantic perspective, I don't think "gay" is a good semantic equivalent to "soppy." The meanings just aren't especially similar. I'd hope user116032 considers the idea that this is one reason the answer is downvoted, rather than speculating that it is because it is just too "honest" or "not PC."

Comment: @sumelic My message was more directed to 116032 than you.

Comment: I never get positive votes.  I'm used to it.  And yes, I don't think people are reading this as anything else but as intended.  I tried to be polite/honest and that's all I can do.  Frank discussions are getting harder and harder to execute.  One must first equivocate.  And frankly, I support the judgmental.  It adds to the mix.  Polite is nice, but that's not always going to get you there.  But polite, really is best.

Comment: Up until about 1970, "gay" (to all but a very few) meant "happy", carrying no negative connotation.  But somewhere before 1980 the use of the term to mean "homosexual" became sufficiently common that it "forced out" the prior meaning.  I can't say for sure, but it seems like the idiom "too gay" or "so gay" (to mean "soppy" or whatever) came into use somewhat later, in a rather sarcastic recombination of the two distinct meanings, and not (strongly) implying that the party discussed was *really* homosexual.

Comment: @Steve Jessop, yeah, I get that 'that's too gay' means 'that's sappy', I didn't realize what user116032 meant. Unrelated: I'm noticing when I move my curser off the text, it (the text) visibly fades. Is this limited to me?

Comment: Your point has (debatably) valid *historical* value but that's no reason to go on about it at length; this is not a "discussion" forum. If your answer read like Hotlicks comment, I *might* have upvoted it, prob no DV, that's for sure. It's a wall of text separated by page breaks; needs better formatting (use of bold, block quotes, ect.) and ideally, links to sites that can substantiate your offering. HTH (honestly, go look up *how to score points on SE*, I'm sure most people here have read the page I'm talking about ;)

Comment: Sorry.  I enjoyed it and just killing time. Points?  I've got my 50 points (so I can comment) and I'm could care less about any more.  Yah... too much.  Will restrain myself in the future.

Comment: It is a somewhat sad fact that, when "gay" was "hijacked" to mean "homosexual", that left us with no good, non-pejorative word to replace it.  "Happy" doesn't quite capture the meaning, and "jolly" is too suggestive of a fat Santa.  "Gleeful" comes close but doesn't "feel" the same in your mouth.