# Alternative to 'gay' in expressions of disdain like "that's so gay"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, pejorative-language

Saying that something is 'gay' is, especially among young people, an oft-heard put-down/insult when describing the disdain and contempt felt toward someone else's cringe-inducing, affected, precious, and pretentious behavior.

[image: Two images: Statement: "I stole her heart, so I'm stealing his last name" Response: "ultra gaaaaaayyyy"]

Linguist [Geoffrey Nunberg explained this NPR](https://www.npr.org/transcripts/105909348); he is quoted below to clarify the scope of this usage:

> Very early on after gay became the acceptable standard name for what we now think of as the gay community, it was transformed into this word that means lame, unpleasant, stupid, sometimes disgusting, whatever.

I currently also use the word in that sense and call cringy/pretentious things/behaviour 'gay'; I want to stop using that word improperly.

So, to summarize: what is an alternative adjective I can use to communicate my disdain when faced with such things? (cringe-inducing, affected, precious, and pretentious)

Comment: [**sappy** or **soppy**](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/262321/what-is-the-us-english-for-soppy) but excluding the inexplicable seal. What's with the seal?

Comment: i understand that it is a "homophobic seal" meme

Comment: This is definitely the most explicitly straight thing I've ever seen anyone describe as gay.

Comment: You could invoke the phony baby talk that some adults use around small children and refer to the behavior you object to as "so pwecious!"—but I'm not sure that would pass muster either, given that it might be interpreted as either (1) mocking  people who have lisps (à la Elmer Fudd), or (2) obliquely alluding to the obnoxious stereotype of gay adults as inveterate lispers.

Comment: gay people tend to find creative ways of drawing attention to social customs, so in an odd sense the word isn't all that far off. the woman could have even got the idea from a gay friend. the problem here is that you intend whatever word you choose pejoratively. since you are interested in being a nicer person, try to focus on your discomfort with melodrama rather than being more cunning in your expression.

Comment: There is a self referential irony to this question but anyway, you may be better off keeping your opinions to yourself. Follow the adage, if you can't say something nice, say nothing. There is no need to quell open shows of affection however embarrassed we are by them. You don't have to join in.

Comment: "to describe the disdain and contempt I feel toward someone else's cringe-inducing, affected, precious and pretentious behavior.

I currently say that behaviour is “gay”  I feel disdain and contempt toward the cringe-inducing use of the word gay here.

Answer (score 33):

cringeworthy seems [reasonably popular](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cringeworthy&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccringeworthy%3B%2Cc0) at the moment.

Comment: +1ing this, but it may be a Briticism. I can't say for sure I've ever heard a US person say it in conversation.

Comment: I'm American, and I use it all the time to describe cheesy, corny, or overwrought things.  (I wouldn't use it to describe OP's picture, but then I'm a romantic.)  But yeah, I use it, and plenty of other Americans I know do too.

Comment: I'm Canadian, and have lived in the US. Very good fit for North America

Answer (score 30):

Here is an adjective for the excessively emotional or sentimental behavior:

---

> [**sappy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sappy) *adjective* U.S.
>
> 3a: **overly sweet or sentimental**
>
> 3b: **lacking in good sense: silly**

(Merriam-Webster *online*)

---

> [**sappy**](http://etymonline.com/index.php?term=sappy&allowed_in_frame=0) (*adj*.) "full of sap," Late Old English *sæpig*, from *sæp* (see sap (n.1)). Figurative sense of "**foolishly sentimental**" (1660s) may have developed from an intermediate sense of "wet, sodden" (late 15c.). Earlier, now obsolete, figurative senses were "full of vitality" (1550s) and "immature" (1620s).

(etymonline)

Comment: For that matter some might actually "describe the disdain and contempt I feel" as "loathsome" and "insufferable". Contempt cuts both ways ;-)

Comment: It's probably worth emphasising that 'sappy' is not really  known or recognised in the UK. I wouldn't have known what it meant before reading this answer.

Comment: @chasly, I included the U.S. designation in the *sappy* definition. It's really our equivalent of your *soppy*.

Comment: My first thought was *mushy*, a synonym for *sappy* which I'm inclined to believe sees more popular usage these days (the NGram comparison supports this inkling).

Comment: Yes *mushy* is good for the *lovey-dovey* aspect but doesn't carry the additional connotation of *silly*, which I think is pertinent here. Thanks for the suggestion, @talrnu. :-)

Comment: I agree with @LittleEva! "Mushy" doesn't cover sappiness in the realm of parental love for children, or twee FB posts about "my baby" that refer to a pet.

Comment: +1 for loathsome. I should use that more in conversation.

Answer (score 21):

I would go with "lame," since it seems to me that people use "gay" to describe lame stuff that isn't necessarily sappy.

Comment: '" I should warn you by using the term 'lame,' you are violating the Americans with Disabilities Act.' - **Lisa Simpson** [Link](http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/view_episode_scripts.php?episode=s20e19) 

Comment: As a historical note, when I was in high school (way back in the early 80's) "lame" was used in the same context that "gay" took over in the mid to late 80's. I refused to switch because the new term seemed to me openly hostile to actual gay people for no good reason. However, the old one ("lame") wasn't exactly friendly to the handicapped either, so I wouldn't suggest it as an alternative.

Comment: Huh, I never thought of that. I guess I've never heard handicapped people described as "lame" (well, outside of Tolkien).

Comment: @T.E.D.: I reckon "lame" is OK.  Yes, at one time it described a person with leg problems, but I don't think it's been used that way in my lifetime.  Go far back enough and "idiot", "moron" and "imbecile" were all *medical terms* describing people with IQs in specific ranges -- should we therefore also avoid these terms?

Comment: @T.E.D.: I guess my question to you then would be whether you find "idiot" et al. to be similarly offensive (or potentially offensive) to "lame".  If not, could you say why not?  As for me, when (years ago) I stopped using "gay" as a synonym for "lame" (having previously used the "two different meanings" "justification") it was because I finally had to admit that, even if the word "gay" had 2 unrelated meanings, those meanings were *simultaneously live* and therefore made it easy for listeners to blur them together, even if that wasn't the speaker's intention.

Comment: @T.E.D. I see you deleted your comment, but I hope you'll put it back up as I'm interested in getting to the bottom of stuff like this!  Rereading my first comment, I admit it strikes me as slightly combative, though I was just going for punchy :)

Comment: MissMonicaE & @j_random_hacker, I'm physically *lame*, but unaffected by the pejorative use of the adjective, but that's not magnanimity, just thick skin (I do however get personally offended by direct quotations that lack source attributions - *go figure*). At the same time though, I won't use *gay* for *lame*, either - I know and love LGBT people. When a label becomes a *person* (as opposed to the opposite) such terms take on significance. *getting to the bottom of stuff like this* leads to one's conscience, let that be your guide. Like the language our consciences are dynamic, also growing.

Comment: [lame](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lame) adjective: 1a: having a body part and especially a limb so disabled as to impair freedom of movement; 1b: marked by stiffness and soreness <a lame shoulder>; 2: lacking needful or desirable substance: weak, ineffectual <a lame excuse>; 3: slang: not being in the know: square; 4a: inferior <a lame school>; 4b: contemptible, nasty <lame racist jokes> (Merriam-Webster online). I would recommend adding muscular features like this to your answers MissMonicaE. More effort is expended, but it will be well-spent and will increase your up-votes.:-)

Comment: @LittleEva, I am aware of the meaning, but I've never heard anyone use it in real life--usually because they said something more specific, like "missing a leg" or "paralyzed from polio" or whatever happens to be true in that case, or something very generic like "handicapped" or "disabled."

Comment: I'm sure I've heard "lame" used in sports commentary in its literal sense, albeit to describe temporary conditions (e.g. a basketball player with an apparent injured ankle, not a wheelchair-basketball player). Although in US sports the most common term seems to be "gimpy". It's also used literally of horses. So while the argument "I don't mean lame as in limping" can't be completely discounted, I believe that the argument "nobody ever uses it to mean limping" cannot.

Comment: I have heard people defend the use of "gay" in this context, with passion, insisting it is a completely different meaning of the word than its meaning as "homosexual". If you don't accept their argument (clearly the OQ doesn't), why would you turn around and accept essentially the same argument for "lame"?

Comment: @T.E.D., are you asking me? I can't tell--you might be talking to Steve Jessop, or someone else entirely.

Comment: "Lame" is an ableist slur. -1.

Answer (score 21):

"**Twee**" has always been my fallback for just this situation. It has just the right level of contemptuous disdain.

Unfortunately, Merriam-Webster.com says it's chiefly British, so it may not work so well universally:

> Twee: adjective \ˈtwē\ : sweet or cute in a way that is silly or sentimental
>
> Chiefly British: affectedly or excessively dainty, delicate, cute, or quaint [such a theme might sound twee or corny — Times Literary Supplement]

---

Edit: Here we are, seven years later, and a neologistic adjective has come along and made all our suggestions moot.

In colloquial US speech, the kind of behavior described in the question is now usually referred to as "**cringe**", likely from "cringeworthy" or "cringe-inducing", but the "-worthy" is now very rarely appended, as cringe has become adjectival on its own.

> cringe (comparative more cringe, superlative most cringe)
>
> (slang) Inducing awkwardness or embarrassment; cringemaking, cringeworthy, cringy.
>
> Antonym: (Internet slang) based

Personally, I still use twee when I can get away with it, though!

Comment: Love this answer.  I'm in the US and have heard this word used correctly before, but you are correct, it is certainly not a very popular word.

Comment: I like this as a replacement for sappy, but it doesn't seem to capture the scorn. But I'm gonna have to slip this into a conversation.

Comment: I love this term, *twee*, brand new to me, +1 Dewi.

Comment: I love "twee" precisely _because_ it's so obscure in the U.S. That means it could potentially obtain the same level of scornful disdain as "gay" currently does if enough people use it with that connotation. Brilliant answer.

Answer (score 7):

To refer to the behaviour that you find objectionable (in others), I would suggest a more neutral but nevertheless descriptive word: **saccharine**, which means artificially sweet to a distastefully excessive extent.

As per the [Merriam Webster dictionary](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/saccharine):

> Full Definition of SACCHARINE
>
> 1. (a) :  of, relating to, or resembling that of sugar 
>      (b) :  yielding or containing sugar
> 2. overly or sickishly sweet
> 3. ingratiatingly or affectedly agreeable or friendly
> 4. overly sentimental :  mawkish 
>      — sac·cha·rin·i·ty \ˌsa-kə-ˈri-nə-tē\ noun

The last three meanings are pertinent.

Comment: "Mawkish" is a perfectly good word to use here too!

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest "pathetic".

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pathetic):

> 1 : having a capacity to move one to either compassionate or contemptuous pity
> 2  : marked by sorrow or melancholy : SAD
> 3 : pitifully inferior or inadequate
> *the restaurant's pathetic service*
> 4  : ABSURD, LAUGHABLE

A combination of definitions 1 & 4 would appropriately convey the condescension you feel toward something ridiculous.

Answer (score 6):

I'm surprised I haven't seen this posted, but I would think **gross**. It's short and well-known so it works well as a replacement pejorative.

**[gross:](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gross)**

> 6a :  coarse in nature or behavior
>
> 6b :  gravely deficient in civility or decency
>
> 6c :  inspiring disgust or distaste

Comment: I think this is perfect. The same people I know who use "gay" in this context also use "gross" almost interchangeably.

Comment: +1 for this oldie-but-goodie, GDanger!

Answer (score 4):

I would consider an action rather than a word. For example you could pretend to vomit/wretch or make a disgusted face. This has a bit more effect than some of the words suggested, which to my ear sound a bit dated.

In text, emojis/emoticons are perfect!

> :-#
>   :|
>   =/

or even better (on devices which can render colour emoji)

> 

---

(Note: As a gay person myself, this use of "gay" doesn't really bother me, I realise words have different meanings and language evolves, but I'm only a very small sample size and don't necessarily represent the majority. I understand why you might want to stop using it.)

Comment: I dig your emojis James, and I've already up-voted so I can't do it again (but I would).  ;-)

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are confusing camp and kitsch. Camp is phony, self-obsessed, over-the-top theatrical attention-whoring. It was very strongly associated with gays before they were main-streamed and reality TV basically obsoleted it. From WordNet 3.0

> camp
>
> adj 1: providing sophisticated amusement by virtue of having artificially (and vulgarly) mannered or banal or sentimental qualities ...
>
> n 6: something that is considered amusing not because of its originality but because of its unoriginality ...

Kitsch doesn't have the same associations with gays/the theatre/Hollywood. From WordNet 3.0

> kitsch
>
> n 1: excessively garish or sentimental art; usually considered in bad taste
>
> kitschy
>
> adj 1: effusively or insincerely emotional

Saying something is kitsch is like calling something tripe, when some people actually like tripe, although it is widely considered to be in bad taste. Calling it treacle, or sap, or pablum more strongly implies that it is puerile (or juvenile).

Comment: If "camp" was "strongly associated with gays" within living memory then it seems plausible that the derogatory use of the word _gay_ originally _may have been_ an intentional reference to the homosexual sense of _gay_. Thank you for bringing up this interesting word association.

Answer (score 2):

The first two may be a bit too British (I'm not sure from where the questioner originates). The third is North American but I certainly hear it a lot in the UK.

**[wet:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/wet)** *Brit. Inf.* Sense #2 "Showing a lack of forcefulness or strength of character"

**[moist:](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Moist&defid=8181896)** *Urban Dictionary* " "... used to describe an 'uncool' person"

**[sappy](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/sappy)** *Inf.* *chiefly North American* Mawkishly over-sentimental

Answer (score 0):

**[poncey:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/poncey)** *Brit.* pretentious or affected
**[pansy:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pansy)** effeminate or homosexual
If you're a Beavis & Butthead fan [**wuss**](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=wuss)

Comment: **+1 for *poncey***, but **-1 for *wuss*** which means = lacking testicles = pussy = lacking courage and ferocity. *Wuss* is a devious euphemism used by those who lack the courage to come right out and say *pussy*, and how wonderfully ironic that is. It would seem that *pansy* is the swing vote here, and ... I'm sorry but *pansy* wouldn't be a good replacement for *gay*, IMO, because it means the exact same thing and, if anything, it's even more derogatory, so **-1 for *pansy***. Beavis & Butthead are your saviors though, I hafta laff at them, so the final tally is ... **+1**!

Comment: You're very kind @LittleEva. But every time theres something gay playing on the telly, they call it wuss music. So I figured I might as well suggest it.

Comment: Ehehe ehe heh heh... duh, what is that funny squiggly thing you guys, are like, putting between their names? Beavis *[and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Beavis_and_Butt-head_titlecard.png)* Butthead, *truly* setting a standard of English unseen since Shakespeare & the King James Bible...

Answer (score -2):

For *garish*, the 1913  *Webster's* has:

> 2. Gay to extravagance; flighty. 
>      [1913 Webster]

So even the dictionary associates it with the old non-politicized meaning of *gay*.

Comment: This suggestions doesn't seem to be for what the OP is asking about.